# How to add multiple read-only columns to Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, read-only

I am creating a Sharepoint List in Sharepoint Online.
I am uploading from an excel file and
I want all the columns to be read-only except for something like 'Status' or 'Notes.'

When I upload from Excel, the columns come in as editable, and the only way I know how to make them read only is to create a Calculated field using the editable field that was migrated from Excel, then hide the editable field.

This is a manual process and I have to do if for every column by clicking through Sharepoint List front-end.

Is there a way to have a script or something that will accomplish this for all the fields. I [was looking at powershell scripts that might do this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/02/powershell-to-create-multiple-fields-in-sharepoint-online-list-from-a-csv.html), but I do not have administrator privileges in powershell

Answer (score 0):

Please run following PowerShell.

Note: The account to be used in the PowerShell should be the administrator of the site collection.

1.Create a csv file as following picture shows.

[image]

2.Please run below PowerShell.

```
 $Credentials=Get-Credential  
 $SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/emilytest"
 $ListName = "list1"

 #Connect to PnP Online
 Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive

 #Get the Context
 $Context = Get-PnPContext

 $filePath = “the local path of csv file, such as C:\columns.csv”  

 $csv = Import-Csv $filePath  
 $a = $csv.ColumnName

 ForEach($_ in $a) {  

      $_.ReadOnlyField = $True
      $_.Update() 
      $Context.ExecuteQuery() 

 }
```